# Bash: command not found and file name too long in variable assignment

Tags: bash

I'm doing the following assignment in my bash script but keep receiving weird errors when not doing it inline.

**Original that works**

```sh
$DB_ENV = $(echo "$(cat .dbenv)" | tr '\n' ' ')
echo "CACERT=\"$(cat .cacert)\" $DB_ENV" yarn run knex migrate:up | bash -
```

**New that doesn't**

```
#!/bin/bash

$DB_ENV=$(echo $(cat .env) | tr '\n' ' ')
$CACERT="CACERT=\"$(cat .cacert)\""

if [[ $1 != 'up' && $1 != 'down' ]]; then
  echo Available subcommands are "up" and "down"
else
  echo "$CACERT $DB_ENV yarn run knex migrate:$1" | bash -
fi
```

For some reason, on the first variable assignment line I'm getting

```
migrate.sh: line 3: =NODE_ENV="production": command not found
```

and on the second

```
migrate.sh: line 4: =CACERT="<file contents with newlines>": File name too long
```

Genuinely confused as to why this is happening, any help would be great!

Comment: are you sure your `Original that works` **really** works? consider cutting-n-pasting your code into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for some recommendations

Comment: If the first snippet worked, you are not using Bash. Either way, you want to get rid of the [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) and the [useless `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo).

Comment: You are attempting to pass the contents of `CACERT` as a command to Bash for execution. That makes no sense, to the point that we cannot guess what you are hoping this code should do instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two erros:

- You should not have `$` in front of variables when assigning to them.
- Do not put a space on either side of assignments `=`.

As an example, your first line should be

```sh
DB_ENV=$(echo "$(cat .dbenv)" | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Comment: *facepalm* this is what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: That could be simplified to `DB_ENV=$(tr '\n' ' ' < .dbenv)`.